# why customize the sources.list with my own deb always failed to locate the deb for Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu-16.04, apt-get

here is my issue background, I need to install postgresql and mongodb on one off-line server, so I copied the deb file from one server which already installed postgresql and mongodb properly, but at last step when I try sudo apt-get install on off-line server, I always get below error:

**E: Failed to fetch file:/var//var/debs/postgresql-10_10.4-2.pgdg16.04+1_amd64.deb  File not found - /var//var/debs/postgresql-10_10.4-2.pgdg16.04+1_amd64.deb (2: No such file or directory)**

below is my step:

1. tar the debs and copy to the off-line server
2. execute follow commands in off-line server

   sudo cp -r path/debs/* /var/debs/

   sudo touch /var/debs/Packages.gz

   sudo chmod -R 777 /var/debs/

   sudo dpkg-scanpackages debs  /dev/null  | gzip > debs/Packages.gz
3. update the /etc/apt/sources.list and do apt-get update

   here is how the sources.list looks like:
   I removed all the other deb, only keep one line which is the path I copied the deb from the server which has postgresql and mongodb installed.

   **deb file:/var debs/**

   then I run sudo apt-get update, and run install but always be told the deb can not found, I am thinking should the sources.list I use is wrong format, hope someone can help me, thanks alot.

Comment: I believe this is unrelated to postgres or mongodb and those tags are unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

not sure what's the issue about the sources.list, but I changed the location to /packages, and updated the sources.list like below, then apt-get install works.

**deb file:// /packages/**

be careful here //space/packages